# Alignment of contents similar to tabular in a multicol environment

Tags: align

I have placed a multicol environment in the middle of a page with 3 columns as you can see in the followning image:

[image]

In each column I want the contents to be aligned one under the other as if there were a tabular environment. I say as if there were bacause I tried using a tabular but it didn't break in the 3 columns. So what is the correct way to do this?

A MWE with my current code is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{3}

BIT0\quad 0x0001

\3

BIT1\quad 0x0002

\3

BIT2\quad 0x0003

\3

BIT3\quad 0x0004

\3

BIT4\quad 0x0005

\3

BIT5\quad 0x0006

\3

BIT6\quad 0x0007

\3

BIT7\quad 0x0008

\3

BIT8\quad 0x0009

\3

BIT9\quad 0x0010

\3

BIT10\quad 0x0011

\3

BIT11\quad 0x0012

\3

BIT12\quad 0x0013

\3

BIT13\quad 0x0014

\3

BIT14\quad 0x0015

\3

BIT15\quad 0x0016

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
BIT13\quad
```

by

```
\makebox[3cm][l]{BIT13}
```

or whatever width you want for the first "column"

Comment: Isn't this going to align only the BIT1, BIT2 etc and not the other "column" with the numbers?

Comment: @Adam -- what this does is force the first "column" to have a uniform width, after which the second "column" will by necessity start in the same horizontal position.

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation and for the solution! It works perfectly!